# similarity between pattern ( regex ) and the value found

Tags: java, regex, ocr, error-correction

I have an image that contains textual information and:

1. I extract/crop a small image from it
2. I am using an OCR to extract the text from the small image
3. Check if the extracted value matches a pattern ( Float , date ...) if so
4. I store the value in database

the problem is : sometimes the ***ocr*** extracts a value with some symbols in it so it doesn't match the pattern example : for the pattern date  i have :

```
pattern = "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\d\d"
```

the value from the image is

```
12/02/2014
```

but the OCR extracted :

```
12? /02 -2014
```

i want to get the similarity between the pattern and the value extracted ( to treat it lately ) is there a way to do that without changing the pattern ?

Comment: It really depends on the accuracy of your OCR software and the quality of the material you are scanning. There could be various errors - the question mark added (uncertain match, marked by the OCR), mismatched characters - e.g. l or I instead of 1, O or o instead of 0, etc.
I would suggest that you allow for some preprocessing of the OCR material and then to try to parse with regexp.

Comment: yes it depends on it , but i don't have the choice i have to take in consideration a value with great similarity to the pattern even if it's not matched

Comment: Could you allow your customers to edit the text recognized by the OCR module, before processing it with the regexp module?

Comment: Also, what concrete thing does *great similarity* represent.

Comment: Basically to my understanding the OP asks if there is a way to cope with the errors/uncertain matches from the OCR software, and use some regexp to identify that the captured data could be: float, date, number, etc...

Comment: The short answer is: no - you cannot match for visual similarity or do a partial match with regexp (unless you create some really complex regexp)

Comment: Check the last comment here for an hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988129/preg-replace-accounting-for-similar-texts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A specific regex cannot be used to match a pattern with ambiguities without modifications that allow such ambiguities. For example, if you would like to allow an insertion of extra characters in arbitrary spots of the string being matched, the regex pattern would need to have provisions that much these arbitrary characters. This makes the pattern ugly very quickly: for example, while a pattern for matching an `int` is very simple,

```
\\d+
```

the same pattern that allows non-digits in between would look like this:

```
(\\d\\D*)+
```

This gets uglier and uglier as the pattern gets larger, so this approach is not very good.

I would recommend replacing a pattern-based matching with an algorithm that implements a variation of [*Levenshtein distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

The original Levenshtein distance algorithm takes two strings, and returns the number of modifications that need to be done on one string in order to get the other one. Your algorithm should take a string and a pattern. The pattern should use some sort of a designator for digits (say, `#`) and treat all other characters "literally", as string characters. You would modify the *indicator function* used in the algorithm to return zero when you send it a `#` and *any* digit, and `1` otherwise.

Take a look at the implementation with two matrix rows, it is the most space-efficient. The indicator function is implemented on this line:

```
var cost = (s[i] == t[j]) ? 0 : 1;
```

Changing it to

```
int cost = (s[i] == t[j] || (Character.isDigit(s[i]) && t[j] == '#')) ? 0 : 1;
```

would allow you to "match" digits. Your code could also remove all whitespace from the string before doing the match.

You could decide on the quality of the match by checking the Levenshtein distance. A distance of zero shows a perfect match; a distance of one or two is pretty good for short patterns; a distance of five or more is probably unacceptable.

Comment: I started looking for some kind of a soundex algorithm for numbers, but the approach you are suggesting looks like a better way to go. One question - could the Levenshtein distance algorithm be adopted for "noise characters" - e.g. extra spaces, question marks, one symbol recognized by the OCR as two characters, etc.?

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev Yes, you can do that, too, by changing the cost function. For example, you can penalize a mismatch with a "noise" character with a smaller cost than a mismatch with a "real" character by assigning a larger (say, 5) value to `cost` when the input has a regular character, and `1` for a mismatch with a "noise character".

Comment: the example you used ( int cost ) is only applicable for pattern int or a short pattern ?

Comment: @manu I wouldn't use a pattern to distinguish an `int` from a `short` - it's doable, but it is too complicated. I would recognize a number with no sign or decimal point (in reality, that is what the pattern represents) and then tried to see if it fits in a byte, then in a short, in an int, or in a long.

Comment: can't you give an example ?

Comment: @manu Assuming that you are implementing the approach above, you could use `#####` pattern for `short`, which might end up `int`, and `##########` pattern for `int`, which might end up `long`. First do the match, and then if the match looks agreeable, extract the digits, build the value, and compare it to the MAX value of the corresponding type (`32767` for a `short`, `2147483647` for `int`). If the value fits in the limit, it's a `short` or an `int`. Otherwise, it's an `int` or a `long`.