# preg_replace accounting for similar texts

Tags: php, regex, levenshtein-distance, sentence-similarity

I'm trying to do a preg_replace taking into account *similar texts* in pattern.
My goal is to remove a given string from a text outputted by an OCR software (some letters may be confused).

Let's give a code example:

```
$ocr = 'Appartamento sito in Vioolo San Vincenzo, n.4 e censito al ;
preg_replace('#\bVicolo San Vincenzo[, ]+([0-9]+|n[\.]? ?[0-9]+)?\b#', '<removed text>', $ocr);
```

NB: **OCR confused the third letter, a `c`, with an `o`**.

Improving OCR is not an option or possible here.

Input string:

> Appartamento sito in Vioolo San Vincenzo, n.4 e censito al

Expected result after the above call to preg_replace:

> Appartamento sito in  e censito al

Actual result:

> Appartamento sito in Vioolo San Vincenzo, n.4 e censito al

Texts should be considered similar in the meaning of PHP functions like `levenshtein()`, `similar_texts()` (while I'm not considering `soundex()` or `metaphone()` as texts aren't in English language).

Using `preg_replace` is not mandatory, but I need at least the ability to evaluate strings against something equivalent to that pattern.

Comment: What do you want to end up with? It seems that you are removing most of the string.

Comment: It was an example @Michael. There is text before and after the part I'm trying to remove

Comment: Could you update the question with this example showing input data, good result, bad result

Comment: updated question @Michael

Comment: Hmm and no parts of the input string is fixed right. You want to capture the first and last part and match the middle part if it has close distance? Is there some structure to the input string. If not it could be hard. It it is streetnames that you want to remove perhaps you could use Google Map lookup. In return you'll get a correct spelling. Match your distance function with any parts of input string and then remove of distance is low enough.

Comment: I want to remove all strings "Vicolo San Vincenzo" from the input text, accounting for spelling mistakes. No need to capture anything now. Google Maps is a good idea, but I don't know what is the address and what not: the input text is a free text, I cannot assume anything about the content.

Comment: "Match your distance function with any parts of input string and then remove of distance is low enough." this seems a good idea. I know the length N of the string to be removed, so I may do a for cycle on the input string, advancing one char a time, and check if the substring of length N starting from this char "matches" or not with levenshtein algorithm. I'll let you know my results.

Comment: I ended up with another approach, as the main reason for removing addresses is to clear the text before trying to recognize numbers that have special meaning for us.